# Making radio button as a required field using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am creating login page using bootstrap, here is my code

```
  <form class="form-signin" action="firstLogin.action" method="post">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="User Name"     
       required="required" autofocus>
    <br>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required="required" 
       placeholder="Password">
    <br>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 150px">Admin</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 150px">User</button> 
    </div>
   <div><br></div>

   <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
 </form>
```

I want to make radio button field as required field . any idea how to do it.?

Comment: You could just check if it is empty or not, in case of empty stop to going further, if not check format, type of data... and go on

Comment: Thanks .. but can we do it as 
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="User Name" required="required">
http://stackoverflow.com/users/2886003/llopis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it!

All you need to do is

-create two divs, one for data-toggle and child her with btn-group

Therefore, you get a group of buttons with a radio inside. set those radio btns to

> class="sr-only"

```
<form class="form-signin" action="firstLogin.action" method="post">
 <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="User Name" required autofocus>
<br>
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required placeholder="Password">
<br>


                <div data-toggle="buttons">
                <div class="btn-group">

                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="type" id="type" value="admin" class="sr-only" required>Admin
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        <input type="radio" name="type" id="type" value="user" class="sr-only" required>User
                    </label>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

<br>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nteb4/23/

It's working on bootstrap3

Comment: it doesnt work unless you select "user" if you click on "admin" doesnt let you submit the form

Answer (score 17):

In order to make input required, the element must be an input element. Change your buttons to inputs, give them a name, add required, and change the type to 'radio', and required should work ([see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/RjwzD/)):

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" required>Admin</input>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" required>User</input> 
</div>
```

Unfortunately this means they don't look like cool buttons anymore. You can style radio buttons to look like what you want, and required will still stop the form from submitting, but you won't see the popup warning to select an option ([see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/SEGAQ/2/)).

So, for what you want, it looks like you'll have to do some basic programming. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/3pQKy/3/) with a basic check in place using your original buttons.

Comment: I know this .. but im asking about can we do it as im saying, by using bootstrap radio buttons.

Comment: YES it works great using bootstrap too i recently used it and is working with just a simple required attribute

Comment: I wish I could vote twice here. This answer is so much simpler than the other popular answer.